# Can I do a swipe (left or right) in Chrome (PC) with a mouse?

Tags: google-chrome, jquery-mobile

I'm building out my jquery mobile app out and have been testing in Chrome.  Its the best for me because the debugging is great.

I was using a TAPHOLD event but decided to go away from that for a swipe-right event.

Chrome actually registered the taphold, so I was hopeful that it would register a swipe right with the mouse.  But I cannot get it to register unless I have to do something else... anyone?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A lot of the answers here are old and out of date.  As of Chrome 63, swipe is built-in as long as you are in responsive mode with developer tools open.  So open Developer Tools (3 dots->tools->developer tools), then click the phone/tablet icon on the left to put Chrome into a mobile mode.  Then if you left click and hold, you will see the cursor changed to a dot, and you can swipe.

Comment: I'm not in a position to validate this right now but I would totally assume you are correct (based on your rep).  This question was asked years ago, so Im switching the answer to this one.

Comment: Incredible! works on Firefox too. Also enables inspecting the UI on a mobile screen

Answer (score 19):

By now the actual chrome developer tools (tried chrome 20) can emulate touch and swipe events.
You can activate that behavior through the tool options, accessible via the little gear-wheel in the bottom corner.

Just check "Emulate touch events" from the options. Then you can also swipe with your mouse.

Comment: You've got to have the developer tools open for the touch events to work, in my experience.

Comment: @Jasper Thanks for the quick tip, it wasn't working before as the developer tools was closed.

Answer (score 11):

In desktop browsers I tend to use the right mouse button testing swipes. It will open a context-menu but it actually works (I normally use Chrome 17 and Firefox 10).

For instance when left-clicking and then swiping on an image in Chrome or Firefox it selects the image and you are then moving around the transparent thumbnail of the image. But when right-clicking and swiping the swipe event is fired.

**UPDATE**

This update is pretty late to the punch but this just shouldn't be necessary anymore. In fact the Chrome developer tools (the ones I'm used to using) have gotten a lot better about emulating devices.

Comment: HOLY moly!  It worked!! I would never have guessed!  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 9):

**Update: this appears to be enabled in Chrome by default (37.0.2062.120 as of September 2014) you do the following:**

1. Open Developer Tools
2. Click the little **phone icon** next to the search icon in the upper left (next to the Elements tab)
3. In the **Emulation** tab on the bottom choose a device model from the drop down

---

Previous answer:

To get this working in the current version of Chrome (32.0.1700.107 as of Feb 2014) you do the following:

1. Open Developer Tools
2. Click the **gear** icon in the upper right
3. Select the **Overrides** tab on the left
4. Click on **Show 'Emulation' view in console drawer**
5. Close the Settings popup
6. Open the Console (button to the left of the gear)
7. Click the **Emulation** tab in the console (next to Console and Search)
8. Choose a device and click on **Emulate** (and click **Reset** to cancel emulation)

Comment: I can't get swipe working on latest Chrome on Mac OS X: Chrome Version 39.0.2171.65 (64-bit). Testing it with www.swipejs.com